# How to move list to the top of my page

Tags: html, css

**Hi guys**, I have a problem where I am trying to push my data inside of the categories TD to the top of the TD instead of it being centered in the TD. Here is the link to my website: [www.thetotempole.ca](http://thetotempole.ca/totempoletemplate42.html)

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-serif;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
    max-width: 768px;
}

#categories {
    float:top;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="lightgrey" id="body" border="1">

<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<img style="width:100%; max-width: 768px; padding:0px; margin:0px;" src="images/totempolebanner.gif">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="width:80%;">
<h3>Newest Article</h3>
<br />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</td>
<td style="width:20%;">
<div id="categories"
<h4>Categories</h4>
<ul>
<li>News</li>
<li>Movies</li>
<li>Music</li>
<li>Video Games</li>
<li>Health</li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
```

Comment: `top` is not a valid value for `float`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give that table cell the CSS, `vertical-align:top`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CQX89/)** (image removed from fiddle for easier viewing)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#body td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First close properly your div categories tag. And then you only need to give to your div an absolute position, and top 0px;

```
#categories {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```